# Three questions for usage of article

Tags: articles

1. Is it necessary to use article for singular, countable noun? Would it be ALWAYS wrong to NOT use article(a, an, the) for such singular noun?
2. When is it appropriate to NOT use article for noun?
3. I am always confused about whether I should treat amorphous object, such as beauty, happiness, and so forth, as countable or uncountable noun. Is there any clear guideline?

Comment: You will find lots of useful websites on this question if you google **use of articles before nouns**

Comment: *Is it necessary to use **an** article for singular, countable **nouns**?* As a rule, yes (there are a *lot* of missing articles in your question text).